# What is the left, right, and ground of this male stereo jack?

Tags: soldering, stereo

I have a male stereo jack that I took apart from my old dead ear buds and I decided that I want to build a new set of earbuds with the stereo jack. Problem is I don't know what parts are the left, right, and ground for this stereo jack since it is a different design compared to others I found online. I am particularly new to this so any help would be appreciated.

[image: This is the stereo jack]

Comment: Did you google the pinout for earbuds?

Comment: I did but I couldn't find any specifically for the design above

Comment: `"...for this stereo jack since it is a different design compared to others I found online."` This looks very similar to any other male stereo jack... can you explain how it's different? There's no other way we can help you unless you know something about this part. Like, where did you get this part? Who's the manufacturer?

Answer (score 6):

For Jack Plugs, aka TRS connectors (Tip, Ring, Sleeve), the standard can be remembered by the *Three R's*

**R**ed **R**ight **R**ing

The **RIGHT** channel is on the **RING** of a TRS connector, on the **RED** wire in a lead, and on the **RED** one of a pair of mono sockets.

Answer (score 4):

The picture is a 3.5mm or 2.5mm stereo connector.

[image]

Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)