# Question about a jack part and how to wire it in Altium?

Tags: audio, components, altium, symbol, diy

[image]I am trying to understand these part labels, "tip", "sleeve" and "ring." I want to route one pin to ground in Altium and the one pin for the left audio and another pin for the right audio. This is supposed to be for the input of the LM386 op amp. Eventually the left and right audio wires will combine as the input.

I did this on a breadboard and had to cut an audio wire and split it into the left, right and ground wires. The left and right audio wires went into a potentiometer and then the common pin of the potentiometer was the input to the LM386.

Is this even the right part? I'm trying to find an audio and it says phone audio (?) I am going to get a 3.5 mm male to male cable and connect it from my laptop to this jack on the PCB.

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/CUI-Devices/SJ-3523-SMT-TR?qs=WyjlAZoYn51zOHzJ3r4ZRA%3D%3D

I couldn't find anything on mouser for a 3.5 mm audio jack that has a footprint for the left audio, right audio and ground.

Comment: Sleeve goes to ground. Tip is left, ring is right. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331190/what-is-the-left-right-and-ground-of-this-male-stereo-jack

Comment: @danmcb perhaps write that as an answer for posterity

Comment: keeps getting turned into a comment. brevity is not appreciated anymore it seems, and I honestly can't be bothered.